# Vue JS value is not updating even though it can be logged in Mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom range slider, which I am trying to display a value inside it. I managed to get my slider to work with vinila js that I have sitting in the 'mounted()' life cycle hook. however even though I can log the value from within this hook it does not render or update the data value.

I am fairly new to Vue but I am thinking that this somehow needs to work in the computed object but don't know how I would do that either,

```
<template>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="slider" />
    <div id="selector">
        <div class="selector-thumb">
           <p>{{rangeValue}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <p>R5 000</p>
        <p>min</p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:auto">
        <p >R200 000</p>
        <p >max</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data:function(){
        return{
            rangeValue:0
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
        var selector = document.getElementById("selector");

        slider.oninput = function(){
            selector.style.left = this.value + "%";
            this.rangeValue = this.value;
            console.log(this.rangeValue)
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: pls never use `document.getElementById(...)` please. you are using an framework you dont need that stuff

Comment: `this.rangeValue` in your case sets `this` for `slider.oninput`, not for Vue object. Use arrow function instead (`slider.oninput = () => { /* Code here */ }`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. Dont use `document.getElementById()` or something like that. You work with an framework you dont need it.

```
<template>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input v-model="rangeValue" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider"  />
    <div :style="{left: rangeValue + '%'}" id="selector">
        <div class="selector-thumb">
           <p>{{rangeValue}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <p>R5 000</p>
        <p>min</p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:auto">
        <p >R200 000</p>
        <p >max</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data:function(){
        return{
            rangeValue:50
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

In case you need to access the element, for what ever reason because there is no other way, you should do it with `ref` like:

```
<div ref="myBox"></div>
```

and then you can access your element with: `this.$refs.myBox`

Note here: If you try to access the element within an `mounted` or `created` you will probably get an `undefined` because the element is not rendered yet. You will need to use `$nextTick()` to make sure everything is rendered and ready for access.

```
this.$nextTick(()=> {
   let element = this.$refs.myBox;
})
```

It also has Promise support

```
await this.$nextTick();
let element = this.$refs.myBox;
```

Sure the method `created` or `mounted` would need to be an async.

Answer (score 0):

Your `function()` doesn't keep track of `this.`. You have to use an arrow function in this case

```js
slider.oninput = () => {
  selector.style.left = this.value + "%";
  this.rangeValue = this.value;
  console.log(this.rangeValue)
}
```

This should keep the reference to `this` intact and lets you access your data.

Edit: Posted a little too quick. I don't see where you get `this.value` from. It isn't defined in your vue-data. Only `this.rangeValue` should be accessible at this point

Comment: this.value refers to the slider element's value